# Pip returns the same error all the time (Hide_cursor)

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have a problem when I use Pip on my computer. Whatever I do, it returns:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'HIDE_CURSOR' from 'pip._vendor.progress' 
(/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/progress/\__init\__.py)
```

Even with `pip list`, it returns the same error.

Currently, I am using Manjaro Linux.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6261

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue on GitHub about the problem:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6261

If anyone has the same problem, here is what I did:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
python3.7 -m ensurepip
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: There should be no need to delete the complete site_packages folder. Best solution would be to remove pip with your packagemanager (if available) and reinstall it. Otherwise removing just `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip` and continuing with @Daniel answer should also work.

Comment: Small addition, I'm on Arch Linux and had to reinstall python, and then pip: pacman -S python; pacman -S python-pip

Comment: This works for me： `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py `. This should work both in Linux and Windows with necessary change, e.g, python get-pip.py or py -3 get-pip.py. Other download methods such as curl etc can be used as well.  I tried various other methods mentioined above, none worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Either your installation of `pip` got corrupted or there is a bug in pip. Try to reinstall the package.

If that doesn't help, try to download a newer/older version of pip using the instructions here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

If that doesn't help, report a bug: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues